# load data into an array using for loop android

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, image-caching

I am trying to populate an array of image urls from Post class but the activity returns a blanked page. am i doing it right. sorry am learning android don't know much.

ArrayList PostDetails = new ArrayList();

```
    for (int index=0;index<imageUrls.length;index++){
        imageUrls[index]=PostDetails.get(index).getImag();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wait till the task is completed, you can put the last part in `onPostExecute` method..

```
protected void onPostExecute( ) {
    String[]imageUrls= new String[PostDetails.size()];

   for (int index=0;index<imageUrls.length;index++){
       imageUrls[index]=PostDetails.get(index).getImag();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Nunu is correct, but I would like to expand on it a little.  The assumption is that `loadingTask` is an `AsyncTask`, thus when you call `execute` the code within `doInBackground` will execute asynchronously.  The code where you create and populate the array will execute in parallel to your population of `PostDetails`, which I assume is populated within the `loadingTask`.  Since the array loop will execute very quickly, it will have completed long before the network operation performed by `loadingTask`.  Thus your page is blank because you have looped through the array before `PostDetails` has been populated.

The solution is just as Nunu suggests, which is to move the population of the `imageUrls` array into the `onPostExecute` method of your `AsyncTask`.  Also, any UI manipulation that uses this array should also be moved into `onPostExecute`.